# Entity Framework A parameter binding to the property <property> was not found on the modification function

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm trying to map an entity insertion to a stored procedure. Here's the header of the stored procedure. Notice the last parameter:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_ins_ErpAndType
    @idSite INT,
    @Description NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    ...
    @TypeConstant int
```

here's my mapping:

```
public DbSet<BasicTaxGroup> TaxGroups { get; set; }
public DbSet<AbstractErpSettings> ErpSettings { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<BasicTaxGroup>()
            .ToTable("tbl_TaxGroup")
            .HasKey(t => t.PrimaryKey);
            .Property(b => b.PrimaryKey).HasColumnName("idTaxGroup");

    modelBuilder.Entity<AbstractErpSettings>()
            .ToTable("vw_ErpAndType")
            .HasKey(m => m.PrimaryKey)
            .Map<AcombaErpSettings>(m => m.Requires("TypeConstant").HasValue("1000"))
            .Map<SemErpSettings>(m => m.Requires("TypeConstant").HasValue("1011"))
            .Property(m => m.PrimaryKey).HasColumnName("idERP");

    modelBuilder.Entity<SemErpSettings>()
    .MapToStoredProcedures(s =>
        s.Insert(i => i.HasName("sp_ins_ErpAndType")
                .Parameter(m => m.TypeConstant, "TypeConstant"))
            );
}
```

`SemErpSettings` and `AcombaErpSettings` both inherit from `AbstractErpSettings`.

Now, When I try to add a BasicTaxGroup to its dedicated DbSet I get this error:

> A parameter binding to the property 'TypeConstant' was not found on
>   the modification function 'sp_ins_ErpAndType'. Ensure that the
>   parameter is valid for this modification operation and that it is not
>   database generated.

I also have some other db sets and they all do the same error.

It looks like the stored procedure gets mapped to ALL entity types... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: Sadly no. I've ended up completely giving up mapping anything to stored procedures, and instead rely entirely on EF's linq2sql. I mostly remake the stored procedures in C# and end up with cleaner, smaller code.

Comment: I am having the same problem with adding a custom Delete proc. What I found was if I added the column as a key to the table object it then only worked. So it looks like at least for delete operations, you can only map properties that are part of the clustered index "HasKey" for that object

Comment: Sorry so late, but I just ran into this and fixed it by ensuring [Required] as above my property in the entity and by setting a default value to those S.P. parameters that aren't required.